# Javascript getTimezoneOffset vs moment utcOffset

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I was surprised that `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns the opposite of `moment().utcOffset()`

**Examples:**

- Timezone UTC +08:00 Hong Kong

  - JS: -480
  - Moment: 480
- Timezone UTC -06:00 Central America

  - JS: 360
  - Moment: -360
- Timezone UTC London

  - JS: 0
  - Moment: -0

**Question:**
If I am correct momentjs is returning the correct value. So why is Javascript `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returning the opposite timezone offset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and
>   local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the
>   local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example,
>   if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600
>   will be returned.

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer explains what `getTimezoneOffset` does but Moment.js docs explicitly describe the difference between moment `utcOffset` and the date `getTimezoneOffset`.

> Note: Unlike moment.fn.zone this function returns the real offset from UTC, not the reverse offset (as returned by Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset).

Source: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/